# How to select image src width - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, alert

How do I select the width of selected image on choose file?

```
if(new Image().attr('src').width() < 200){
alert('Expected');

}else{

alert('Woah?');

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "selected image"? You've provided some invalid code. What have you actually attempted so far?

Comment: Yes, the code doesn't seem to be working. '<input type="file">' selected files width is what I want to detect.

Comment: `<input type="file">`*

Comment: You're going to need to do a better job of explaining what you want. Take it a step at a time, and spell it out in your question. The code you provided is an odd mix of function calls that will simply fail.

Comment: ummm... is this code supposed to be valid?

Comment: You can't check the width until the image is uploaded.

Comment: Sorry, for the vague question. I'll try to be more clear. In the `html` code I have used `<input type="file">` and I would like to select a file and if the selected file - ie selected images width is less than `<` `200px` `alert` 'Expected', if not `alert` 'Woah?'

Comment: Oh damn! Okay is there a method of checking it once it's uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the source and width of an image using Javascript (not jQuery specific):

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhAXn/2/), and here's the js code:

```
var test_image = document.getElementById("TestImage");
var test_image_src = test_image.getAttribute("src"); // get the source
var test_image_width = test_image.getAttribute("width"); // get the width

if(test_image_width < 200){
    alert('Expected');
}else{
    alert('[Woah]?');
}
```

You can retrieve any attribute using this method.

var attribute = element.getAttribute(attributeName);
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute

Comment: Thanks very much, I was confused as whether to use jQuery or Pure js Thanks again!

Comment: This answer wan't exactly fit for the `<input>` part of the question. However, I have implemented my own code. THAT WORKS :D